# Separate abline for each facet of an R ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

I want to have a unique abline on each facet of the following plot.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mpg, aes(x = hwy, y = displ, group = 1)) +         
  geom_point() + 
  geom_line() +
  facet_wrap(~ manufacturer, scales = "free")
```

The abline is simply a horizontal line equal to the `'second to last'` y-value (displ) on each facet. As an example the second to last y-value on the Audi facet is 2.0 and the second to last y-value on the Chevrolet facet is 3.5. The big issue is I don't know how to subset my data by facet (assuming this is the approach I *should* take). I assume the FrankenSyntax would be:

```
geom_hline(data = subset(mpg, displ = DEPENDS ON FACET), 
  aes(yintercept = lead(mpg, FACET, 2nd to Last) & lag(mpg, FACET, 2nd to Last)), 
  color = "red"
)
```

I also don't know how to implement `lead()` and `lag()` in this scenario to pull out the second to last value, to use as my abline y-intercept. I know there must be a better way to dplyr this whole thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could achieve that calculating the `mpg %>% arrange(hwy) %>% group_by(manufacturer) %>% mutate(icpet=nth(displ,-2))` intercept value.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mpg %>% arrange(hwy) %>% group_by(manufacturer) %>% 
         mutate(icpet=nth(displ,-2)), 
       aes(x = hwy, y = displ, group = 1)) +         
  geom_point() + 
  geom_line() +
  facet_wrap(~ manufacturer, scales = "free") +
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept=icpet), colour="blue", lwd=2)
```

[image]

The above code can also be written as:

```
mpg %>% arrange(hwy) %>% group_by(manufacturer) %>% 
  mutate(icpet=nth(displ,-2)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = hwy, y = displ, group = 1)) +         
  geom_point() + 
  geom_line() +
  facet_wrap(~ manufacturer, scales = "free") +
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept=icpet), colour="blue", lwd=2)
```

Comment: You need to take the `nth` value of `displ` after sorting on `hwy`. Also you can pipe into the ggplot for clarity. So `mpg %>% 
    arrange(hwy) %>% 
    group_by(manufacturer) %>% 
    mutate(icpet = nth(displ, -2)) %>% 
    ggplot(........)` etc

Comment: @Axeman Thanks for the catch. I have edited my answer.  For your clarity suggestion too.

Answer (score 0):

Prradep was ninety-five percent there. Just needed a few fixes. Here's the final answer.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mpg %>%
         arrange(hwy) %>% 
         group_by(manufacturer) %>% 
         mutate(ref.pt = nth(displ, -2)),
       aes(x = hwy, y = displ, group = 1)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_line() +
  facet_wrap(~ manufacturer, scales = "free") +
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept = ref.pt), color = "red")
```